# derivatives and constants

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am confused on finding the derivative when constants are involved:
with $3\ln(x^4 + \sec x)$
the derivative is
$(3(4x^3 + \sec x \tan x))/(x^4+\sec x)$
notice the three stayed, but with

$x^2+2x+7$
the derivative of seven turns to zero in the answer
$2(x+1)$

my question is what is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that, for any differentiable $f$

$$(f+c)'=f'+0=f'$$

however, $$(c\cdot f)'=c\cdot f'$$

for any constant $c$. That should probably be in your notes.

Comment: Thanks Peter!!! I should have caught that!!!

Comment: What is you have d/dx of (1-cx)^2

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that there is no constant term in the first expression. $3$ there is coefficient, not a constant term!

Comment: OK! Thanks Shu Xiao Li!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $$\frac d {dx} (f(x) +g(x)) = \frac d {dx} (f(x)) + \frac d {dx} (g(x))$$
but 
$$\frac d {dx} (cf(x)) = c \frac d {dx} (f(x)),$$

if $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

As 3 is constant with in multiplication with function therefore 3 can taken outside of differentiation by the rule d/dx(kf(x)) = kd/dx(f(x)) while in second example 7 is constant therefore its differentiation is zero due to rule d/dx(C) = 0 where c = constant